# Regex Removing text before the 5th comma and after the 6th comma

Tags: regex

i have alot of this line

```
('235753', 'BayEnesYT', '$2y$12$laiU7F7HWJoXuryMTmgb6uKDfiOcxqD/R6Mxjg.KVNn2TK/Ra2Vwq', 'BNnuyZNL', 'zb6WPCvWYDwQmwZJQI7sypkc6oqVjZpSvnlg8gYYztJm6JYmJh', 'm.enesberber2009@gmail.com', '0', '0', '', '', '', '2', '', '0', '', '1560100802', '1560689379', '1560102670', '0', '', '0', '', '', '', '', '', 'all', '', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'linear', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '', '0', '0', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '', '0', '0', '0', 0x51D69F63, 0x5567522E, '', '1894', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '', '0', '0.00', '1', '0', '0', '0', '', '1', '1', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '[]', '1', null, null, null, '1', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '0', '', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', 'mybb_bcrypt', '0', '');
```

and i need to remove text  before the 5th comma and after the 6th comma

so the result would be  `m.enesberber2009@gmail.com` only

i want to use regex replacement method with notepad++

Comment: which tool or language you're using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this expression

```
^\(?(?:'[^']*',\s*){5}('[^']+').+
```

with the first captured group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/oHoDrF/1/).

Comment: @sln: Right you are, probably not. But it allowed me to repeat the non-capturing group. Additionally, it may or may not be there, who knows.